# How to manage UIActivityViewController completion?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, uiactivityviewcontroller

to share an image, i swipe it off screen.

What's happening now is:

- i swipe the image
- it presents the UIActivityViewController
- i choose an activity
- the activity shows up modally

if i cancel the activity:

- the image is on screen (the view did load)
- the image move back in

what i need:

- i cancel the activity
- the image is not on screen
- the image move back in

How can i do this ?

here is my code:

```
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [imageToShare], applicationActivities: nil)
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {
        print("presented")
        //self.grids.center = self.offScreenPosition
        print("position share is \(self.grids.center)")
    })

    switch deviceOrientation {
    case "portrait":
        activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {(UIActivityType: UIActivityType?, completed: Bool, returnedItems: [Any]?, error: Error?) in
            if !completed {
                print("cancelled")
                self.moveViewVertically(.backIn, range: self.verticalRange)
            }
            if completed {
                print("completed")
                self.moveViewVertically(.backIn, range: self.verticalRange)
            }
        }
    case "landscape":
        activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {(UIActivityType: UIActivityType?, completed: Bool, returnedItems: [Any]?, error: Error?) in
            if !completed {
                print("cancelled")
                self.moveViewHorizontally(.backIn, range: self.horizontalRange)
            }
            if completed {
                self.moveViewHorizontally(.backIn, range: self.horizontalRange)
            }
        }
    default:
        break
    }
```

prints are there to see what's happening.
it' my first app.
thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is solved.
in the `moveView` method, i wrote `center.y -= 1` to move the view. ie an iteration over a desired range.

now i do:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.grids.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -self.view.frame.height)}
```

it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the view move back before activityViewController dismiss? you can try this: custom a subclass of UIActivity,and then

```
- (void)performActivity {
    // move your view back in
    [self activityDidFinish:YES];
}
```

Comment: no: i need the view to move back after the activity, or after cancellation. the issue now: the view is already there (it did load) and then the animation appens. i need the animation before the view did load.

Comment: But activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler called after animation complete, are you sure "print("cancelled")" or "print("completed")" called before animation?

Comment: yes cancel and completed both print before the image move back in.